# Identify items in list that are already in database and remove them

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, jpql

I have an entity Student as:
ID, name(String), ...

I have another entity ArchivedStudents as:
`ID`, `name`(String), `dateArchived`, ...

I am randomly generating a list of new students and before persisting this list into Student table, I am performing:
From the list of new students, I am trying to remove students with the name that already exists in either Student or ArchivedStudents.

Currently, I am passing in the list of student names and check if already exists in the ArchiveStudent table and then remove duplicates. Then check if the name already exists in the Students table, remove duplicates and then persist the remaining.

The number of records in ArchivedStudents and Student table are in millions.

I wanted to double-check if this is optimal or if there is a better way to do it. I'm using `findAllByStudentIn` method for identifying duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to do it with one shot to the database:

```
List<Student> students = generateRandomStudents();
List<String> namesInDb = (List<String>) entityManager.createQuery("select s.name from Student s where s.name in :names")
    .setParameter("names", students.stream().map(Student::getName).collect(toList()))
    .getResultList();
studentsRepository.saveAll(students.stream().filter(s -> !namesInDb.contains(s.getName())).collect(toList()));
```

Comment: After that, I have to save the filtered list into Student table. Is there a way to save to database and ignore duplicates?

Comment: I'm currently doing the same. Identify duplicates from db, remove them, and save the filtered list. Is there a way to save the list ignoring duplicate names in one go? Right now, checking for duplicates and saving are two calls to the Student table.

Comment: @rohan I'm not really familliar with mysql, but I would try something like `on conflict` clause: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: Trying to not use entity manager and use Spring JPA repository built-in functions if possible. Thanks though!

Comment: @rohan you can pass any sql with `EntityManager#createNativeQuery`

Comment: *Is there a way to save the list ignoring duplicate names in one go* By using the correct solution for the job which is probably a DB stored proc rather than JPA.